# How to find the length of value_counts() that is greater than 1 in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to find the length of number of occurrences in a pandas dataframe column using value_counts()?

`df['Fruits'].value_counts()`

```
Apple        6
Orange       5
Pear         5
Peach        4
Watermelon   4
Strawberry   1
Honeydew     1
Cherry       1
```

when I try to run `len(df['Fruits'].value_counts() != 1)`, my desired output would be:

`5`

However, it end up returning `8` which is the same value as `len(df['Fruits'].value_counts())`

Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for sum instead:

```
df['Fruits'].value_counts().ne(1).sum()
```

If you want to use `len`, you have to filter first:

```
vals = df['Fruits'].value_counts()
len(vals[vals > 1])
```

Comment: can you explain what `[vals > 1]`  ? thanks.

Comment: `vals` contains our value counts, so it returns a boolean Series indicating `True` for each value which has a count of more than 1. Then we pass this boolean to our value counts to only keep those values. @Gel